# what is the function of shrept.lst file and genclntsh.sh? oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I was looking to find the function of "shrept.lst" file in oracle 11g. Its located inside the $Home_directory/network/admin. I did try to search the web for it but didn't find any precise answers. In the header it says # function entry points for genclntsh.sh. and when i tried to search it in this blog as well as oracle community i didn't get the clear description of what this file is used for. I would really appriciate if anyone can guide me.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `genclntsh` script, under `$ORACLE_HOME/bin`, [regenerates the client shared library](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10839/prcmp_cll_int.htm#UNXAR192), `libclntsh.so` (in Unix). You shouldn't normally need to worry about this - it's run automatically on installation and usually during patching or upgrade tasks.

According to that script, "each product *must* provide a $PRODUCT/admin/shrept.lst". It's part of the internal mechanism to determine which symbols should explicitly be undefined by the linker, via the script's `listf()` function. From the `network/admin/shrept.lst` file, the `ld` command will include `-u snaumihi_inithostinfo -u snaumbg_gmt ...`.

The man page for `ld` describes what the `-u` flag does:

> Force  symbol to be entered in the output file as an undefined symbol.  Doing this may, for example, trigger linking of additional modules from standard libraries.  -u may be repeated with different  option arguments to enter additional undefined symbols.  This option is equivalent to the
>   "EXTERN" linker script command.

So the file is for internal Oracle use. If it doesn't exist the linking process will fail (see Oracle Support doc ID 1587532.1 for example). Don't touch it, modify it, or remove it. Just ignore it.